# Default value select list not bound to model on init

Tags: angular

So I have this array in my component:
`vehicleTypes = ['Bicycle', 'Car', 'Motorcycle', 'Van'];`

And I generate the dropdown HTML with:

```
<select id="vehicletype" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicleType" >
    <option *ngFor="let vt of vehicleTypes; let i = index" [selected]="i === 0">{{ vt }}</option>
</select>
```

How do I manage to get the value stored in `selectedVehicleType` when the page is loaded? Now it just shows the first value in the dropdownlist, but `selectVehicleType` is `undefined`. I have to select another value first before it gets stored in `selectVehicleType`.

Please note I'm aware of manually assigning it in the component, but I'd like to know if there is another way in the HTML. I don't want to write extra lines of code in my component every time I need a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around setting the default value of the model, because it's overriding the `selected` attribute binding. Also I'd suggest using the value binding of the option element.

```html
<select id="vehicletype" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicleType" >
    <option *ngFor="let vt of vehicleTypes; let i = index" [value]="vt">{{ vt }}</option>
</select>
```

And in your component you could combine the declaration and setting into one line, so it doesn't add more code than setting it in the template would:

```ts
selectedVehicleType: string = vehicleTypes[0];
```